# CSS grid-gap doesn't exist to screen

Tags: html, css, grid

I'm trying to use the grid structure in CSS3, I can't use the grid-gap feature, when I type grid-gap, it doesn't appear on the screen. Could you help ?

Comment: can you please provide your code?

Comment: I am sending it in the form of a picture so that you can see it more easily. https://files.fm/u/vavdnpf83#/view/9ksgptn4h

Comment: try adding `gap` instead `grid-gap`

Comment: No, it didn't. Have you ever had a problem like this before?

Comment: ️️️ Property is obsolete. Avoid using it.

Shorthand that specifies the gutters between grid columns and grid rows in one declaration. Replaced by 'gap' property.

(Firefox 52, Chrome 57, Safari 10, Opera 44)

Syntax: <'grid-row-gap'> <'grid-column-gap'>?
This is the error, but it doesn't work when using gap.

Answer (score 0):

For adding space between grids you can use `grid`.

I am attaching a reference [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap).

Comment: No matter what I do it doesn't work and I don't know why. I've been struggling for hours. There is probably a very simple solution but I can't find it
No matter what I do it doesn't work and I don't know why. I've been struggling for hours. There is probably a very simple solution but I can't find it

Comment: can you please attach your code to this question? not image

Comment: .container{
    display: grid;
    /* height: 300px; */
    grid-template-areas: 'header header header header header'
    'menu1 main main main right1 right1'
    'menu1 footer footer footer footer footer';
    /* grid-template: repeat(3, 1fr) / repeat(3, 1fr); */
    gap:10px;
    background-color: blueviolet;
    padding: 10px;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.container > div{
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 0;
    font-size: 32px;
}

Comment: and at first there are these

.grid-1{
    grid-area: header;
}

.grid-2{
    grid-area: menu1;
}

.grid-3{
    grid-area: main;
}

.grid-4{
    grid-area: right1;
}

.grid-5{
    grid-area: footer;
}

Comment: I closed and reopened VS Code, rewrote all the code and solved it. Thanks for your interest

Comment: @MetehanYıldırım Nice